# KeyError: 'AK' census2010.allData['AK']['Anchorage']

Tags: python-3.x

```
'''
Reads the data from the Excel spreadsheet.
Counts the number of census tracts in each county.
Counts the total population of each county.
Prints the results.

This means your code will need to do the follwing:
Open and read the cells of an Excel document with the openpyxl module.
Calculate all the tract and population data and store it in a data structure.
Write the dat structure to a text file with the .py extension using the pprint module.

'''
import openpyxl,os,pprint
os.chdir('C:\Python34')
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('censuspopdata.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Population by Census Tract')
CountyData = {}

for row in range(2,sheet.max_row + 1):
    state = sheet['B' + str(row)].value
    county= sheet['C' + str(row)].value
    pop   = sheet['D' + str(row)].value

CountyData.setdefault(state, {})
CountyData[state].setdefault(county, {'tracts': 0, 'pop': 0})
CountyData[state][county]['tracts'] += 1
CountyData[state][county]['pop'] += int(pop)

print('Writing the results...')
resultFile = open('census2010.py', 'w')
resultFile.write('allData = ' + pprint.pformat(CountyData))
resultFile.close()
print('Done')
```

I can't deal with some KeyErrors. I made this program by following the instructions of "Project: Reading Data from a Spreadsheet" on this website: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter12/ 
(I downloaded the excel file from here: https://www.nostarch.com/automatestuff/)

When I typed census2010.allData['AK']['Anchorage'], I got KeyError: 'AK'. I tried typing the other state abbreviations, but it didn't work either. Please help me out with this.

Comment: Check your indentation.

Comment: I still don't see where I should fix. which indentation should I fix?

Comment: Actually, I got it just now. Thanks for your help!